# Check whether the broadcast receiver is already registered?

Tags: java, android

How to check whether the broadcast receiver is already registered in android application programatically?

Answer (score 1):

There is way to check this and more about it can be found on [Android Developer site](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Method called **queryBroadcastReceivers**

Comment: How to use `queryBroadcastReceivers`?

Comment: `val pm = context.packageManager
val broadcastList: List<ResolveInfo> = pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, PackageManager.GET_RESOLVED_FILTER)`

you can adjust according to your code and filters based on : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers(android.content.Intent,%20int)